# Applescript trim movies in quicktime

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I would like to trim a video file per frame number rather than seconds.
So far I have tried a few options and this is the most successful one so far:

```
set start_trim to 5
set end_trim to 6

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    try
        set movieFile to (the POSIX path of ("PathToMovieFolder")) & "MyMovie.mov"
    on error errorMsg number errorNum
        display alert errorMsg & space & errorNum message ¬
            "An error occured trying to find the file " & movieFile & "." & return & ¬
            "Check the file path exists, and the file spelling." as warning giving up after 60
    end try
    try
        open movieFile with presenting
        delay (0.25)
        present document 1
        delay (0.25)
        trim document 1 from start_trim to end_trim
        display alert errorMsg & space & errorNum message ¬
            "An error occured trying to open & play the file " & movieFile & "." & return & ¬
            "Check the file path exists, and the set delay time" as warning giving up after 60
    end try
end tell
```

What it does is that it trims it to seconds rather than exact frames.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame is not in the QuickTime Player dictionary. However, it is in the QuickTime Player 7 dictionary. If you need to trim using frames rather than seconds, I would suggest finding a copy of QuickTime Player 7.

or maybe you could do something like this:

```
set FPS to 29.97
set start_trim to 5
set end_trim to 7

set startFrame to start_trim / FPS
set endFrame to end_trim / FPS

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    trim document 1 from startFrame to endFrame
end tell
```